# Pod Spec Validation Cocoa Pod issue

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, swift, git, cocoapods

I keep getting validation errors when i run pod spec lint. I tried various versions of the pod spec file and it is still not going through. I did create a swift file to point to version 3.0 in github and all other ways to avoid the issue. This is the podspec file I have:

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
s.name         = "SwiftImageCarousel"
s.version      = "1.0.0"
s.summary      = "SwiftImageCarousel is an easy-to-use carousel.”
s.description  = "SwiftImageCarousel is an easy-to-use carousel. Just give it the image URLs, let it do the rest for you!”
s.homepage     = “https://github.com/Centroida/SwiftImageCarousel"
s.license      = "MIT"
s.platform     = :ios, "10.0"
s.source       = { :git => "https://github.com/Centroida/SwiftImageCarousel.git”, :tag => “1.0.0” }
s.source_files = "SwiftImageCarousel", "SwiftImageCarousel/**/*.{h,m,swift,storyboard}”
s.pod_target_xcconfig = { 'SWIFT_VERSION' => '3' }
end

!] Invalid `SwiftImageCarousel.podspec` file: syntax error, unexpected tCONSTANT, expecting keyword_end
...cription  = "SwiftImageCarousel is an easy-to-use carousel. ...
...                               ^
SwiftImageCarousel.podspec:5: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '('
...usel is an easy-to-use carousel. Just give it the image URLs...
...                               ^
SwiftImageCarousel.podspec:5: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '('
... give it the image URLs, let it do the rest for you!”
...                               ^
SwiftImageCarousel.podspec:5: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '('
SwiftImageCarousel.podspec:6: syntax error, unexpected tLABEL
s.homepage     = “https://github.com/Centroida/SwiftImageCarousel"
                          ^
SwiftImageCarousel.podspec:6: unknown regexp options - gthb
SwiftImageCarousel.podspec:6: syntax error, unexpected tSTRING_BEG, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '('
SwiftImageCarousel.podspec:7: syntax error, unexpected tCONSTANT, expecting keyword_end
s.license      = "MIT"
                     ^
SwiftImageCarousel.podspec:8: syntax error, unexpected tFLOAT, expecting keyword_end
s.platform     = :ios, "10.0"
                            ^
SwiftImageCarousel.podspec:9: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_end
...source       = { :git => "https://github.com/Centroida/Swift...
...                               ^
SwiftImageCarousel.podspec:9: unknown regexp options - gthb
SwiftImageCarousel.podspec:9: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting keyword_end
...oida/SwiftImageCarousel.git”, :tag => “1.0.0” }
...                               ^
SwiftImageCarousel.podspec:9: no .<digit> floating literal anymore; put 0 before dot
...eCarousel.git”, :tag => “1.0.0” }
...                               ^
SwiftImageCarousel.podspec:10: unterminated string meets end of file
SwiftImageCarousel.podspec:10: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could the curly quotes be causing trouble?

Comment: It turns out that some of the issues were the quotes. I reset the master and I am restarting the operation, I will give update on what happens.

Answer (score 1):

Taken from https://www.raywenderlich.com/97014/use-cocoapods-with-swift

**Note: You shouldn’t use TextEdit to edit the Podfile because it likes to replace standard quotes with more graphically appealing typeset quotes. This can cause CocoaPods to become confused and results in errors being thrown, so it’s best to use Xcode or another programming text editor to edit your Podfile.**

Turns out it is really important to use the correct quotation marks. Do it! 
Or waste a day with this :)